# Need linq query to obtain specific result set

Tags: c#, linq

If any one can help here to prepare this linq query.

Below is the table data:

```
category question answer user
a1        q1      3        u1
a1        q1      5        u2
a1        q2      3        u2 
a2        q3      3        u3
a2        q3      2        u4
a3        q4      9        u3 
a3        q5      8        u7 
a3        q5      2       u9
```

I need result as below:
group by Category, Question, Result (group with three condition as below).

so, for each category, each question, need to group the result in three form(group by answer (<=3) and one group, answer = 5 and third group answer=8 OR 7 OR 9),

```
category name   Question  TotalCount Ans(<=3) Ans(5)  Ans(7 or 8 or 9)
a1               q1        2              1      1        0
a1               q2        1              1      0        0
a2               q3        1              1      0        0
.....
```

I tried by using below query in SQL (it is not perfect query as i need column for result group instead of record).

```
 SELECT  
Category, Question,
Count(Ans), 
CASE 
    WHEN Ans = 9 OR Ans = 8 OR ans=7 THEN '9 or 8 or 7' 
    WHEN Ans = 5 THEN '5' 
    WHEN Ans <= 3 THEN '<=3' 
END as 'ResultGroup'
FROM 
SurveyQuestions 
GROUP BY 
Category, Question, Ans
ORDER BY 
Question
```

Please guide me how to get the result as shown above. I need `LINQ` query to obtain this result.

thanks

Comment: Thanks for formatting. i was trying same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to group it by answer. Instead filter and count on the answer something like below:

```
from t in db.Table
group t by new {t.Category, t.Question} into g
order by g.Category
select new 
{
    CategoryName = t.FirstOrDefault().Category, //might be required to handle null here
    Question = t.FirstOrDefault().Question, //might be required to handle null here
    TotalCount = t.Count(),
    AnsLessEqual3 = t.Where(d => d.Answer<=3).Count(),
    Ans5 = t.Where(d => d.Answer = 5).Count(),
    Ans789 = t.Where(d => d.Answer = 7 || d.Answer = 8 || d.Answer = 9).Count()
}
```

Although above query is not tested but I believe it would give you quick start for moving forward.

Comment: Thanks so much. It giving me below error when i try to iterate result in `foreach` loop.  `The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.` please guide.